# WPF user control throws design-time exception

Tags: c#, wpf, design-time

I have a userControl which starts a timer. It looks like the XAML designer is trying to call that code, which links to some back-end database stuff. I keep getting an unhanded exception error in the design screen.

Any ideas how I can stop the designer trying to run the code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XAML designer will call the UserControl's constructor when loading in designer. In order to avoid this you can place a if condition as follows in your UserControl constructor

```
if(System.ComponentModel.DesignMode) return;
```

You can also check in this way

```
if (!System.ComponenyModel.DesignProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{ // write constructor code here  }
```

Comment: You can also check in this way If(!System.ComponenyModel.DesignProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)){ // write constructor code here <br/> }

Comment: You sure about this answer? System.ComponentModel should be a name-space, and this makes DesignMode a class, but there is no such thing? Also UserControl doesn't have a System property either so I'm not entirely sure how this should work.